# Full Window Image - Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am trying to adjust the size of an image so that it fits the entire window. When I set the image to the height of the window, there is always a scrollbar on the side of the window and a white space between the bottom of the window and the image. I can not figure out how to get ride of it. *How can I get rid of the space and remove the scroll bar?*

Here is a simple test file. I am using JavaScript because this has to be modular. The ratio and size of the image is known in the full script.

http://sambender.com/test/blank.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide the scrollbar with css's overflow:

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

Not sure what gap you are referring to, I can't see any on my browsers (FF and Chrome)